# Adding to the same array with two different foreach loops PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have seperate tables full of data and I require the same data from each table. For example the first table I am selecting from has the value 3623 and the second table has the value 3852.

I am trying to get both of these values into an array to then be plotted on a graph later down the line. The code I am using can be seen below, the issue is that on the value from the first foreach loop gets added and not the second one. so I end up with just 3623 and not the 3852 as well which is an issue.

```
$datay1 = array();
$yes = "not-set";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `0530-0605` WHERE SearchTerm = :yes";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":yes", $yes);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $datay1[] = $row['Clicks'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `0606-0612` WHERE SearchTerm = :yes";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":yes", $yes);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $datay1[] = $row['Clicks'];
}

print_r($datay1);
```

Comment: This two queries doing the same why u cant use it in one query ?

Comment: Because I am querying two tables, and this will increase to hundrededs over time

Comment: Try with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`UNION ALL`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to merge result of two query as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `0530-0605` WHERE SearchTerm = :yes
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `0606-0612` WHERE SearchTerm = :yes1";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":yes", $yes);
$stmt->bindParam(":yes1", $yes);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $datay1[] = $row['Clicks'];
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, only getting one of the two values

Comment: Is `not-set` is present in second table column value??

Comment: My error, database not re-written correctly, works now, thanks!